# Combining MAX and SUM in an Oracle ROLLUP

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Here's my SQL:

```
WITH source1 AS (
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 20 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 30 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Grape'  food, 1  weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Carrot' food, 40 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Leek'   food, 20 weight FROM dual
)
SELECT grouping(food) lv, foodtype, food, max(weight) weight
FROM   source1
GROUP BY foodtype, ROLLUP (food);
```

The output looks like this:

```
LV FOODTYPE FOOD   WEIGHT
-- -------- ------ ------
0  Veg      Leek       20
0  Veg      Carrot     40
1  Veg                 40
0  Fruit    Apple      30
0  Fruit    Grape       1
1  Fruit               30
```

I was expecting it to look like this:

```
LV FOODTYPE FOOD   WEIGHT
-- -------- ------ ------
0  Veg      Leek       20
0  Veg      Carrot     40
1  Veg                 60
0  Fruit    Apple      30
0  Fruit    Grape       1
1  Fruit               31
```

In other words, I was expecting the `rollup` to sum up the maximum weights of each food instead of taking the maximum of all the maximums in the food-type category.

I do have a solution of sorts, but it means having to add an additional layer of SQL-statement nesting:

```
WITH source1 AS (
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 20 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 30 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Grape'  food, 1  weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Carrot' food, 40 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Leek'   food, 20 weight FROM dual
), source_grp AS (
   SELECT s.foodtype, s.food, max(s.weight) max_weight
   FROM   source1 s
   GROUP BY foodtype, food
)
SELECT grouping(g.food) lv, g.foodtype, g.food, sum(g.max_weight) weight
FROM   source_grp g
GROUP BY g.foodtype, ROLLUP (g.food);
```

Is there a way to do it without the extra nesting?

Of course, this example is significantly simplified from my real-world situation, which is why I'm trying to find a way to reduce the number of lines of code.  Reducing a SQL statement by 60 lines of code significantly eases its maintenance in the long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this after a few days.  It can be done like this:

```
WITH source1 AS (
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 20 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 30 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Grape'  food, 1  weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Carrot' food, 40 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Leek'   food, 20 weight FROM dual
)
SELECT grouping(s.food) lv, s.foodtype, s.food,
       CASE WHEN grouping(s.food)=1 THEN
          sum(CASE WHEN grouping(s.food)=1 THEN 0 ELSE max(s.weight) END) OVER (PARTITION BY s.foodtype ORDER BY s.food)
       ELSE
          max(s.weight)
       END weight
FROM   source1 s
GROUP BY s.foodtype, ROLLUP (s.food)
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure I like this answer either.  Depending on the context and from a maintenance point of view, the `CASE-WHEN` statement is more difficult to understand than the multi-level `SELECT`.

Answer (score -1):

You *could* use `row_number()` instead:

```
SELECT GROUPING(food) as lv, foodtype, food, SUM(weight) weight
FROM (SELECT s1.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foodtype, food ORDER BY weight DESC) as seqnum
      FROM source1 s1
     ) s1
WHERE sequm = 1;
GROUP BY foodtype, ROLLUP (food);
```

Comment: That just plain gives the wrong output, I'm afraid.  I only get the first `food` from each `foodtype`.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse . . . You just need to fix the `partition by` clause.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Even if you fiddle a bit, you're not using fewer numbers of `SELECT` statements than I am in the question. You're just nesting them in a different way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the window function combined with CASE expressionto get the desired result:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f72f1/3)

```
WITH cte1 AS
(SELECT a.*, 
SUM(weight) OVER(PARTITION BY foodtype ORDER BY lv, food rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) cum_sum
FROM table1 a)
SELECT lv, foodtype, food, 
CASE WHEN lv = 1 
     THEN cum_sum
     ELSE weight END AS weight
FROM cte1;
```

You can make use of Union and hence total select will be just 2.

```
WITH source1 AS (
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 20 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Apple'  food, 30 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Fruit' foodtype, 'Grape'  food, 1  weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Carrot' food, 40 weight FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 'Veg'   foodtype, 'Leek'   food, 20 weight FROM dual
)
SELECT foodtype, food, max(weight) weight
FROM   source1
GROUP BY foodtype, food
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT FOODTYPE, NULL, SUM(WEIGHT) TOTAL_WEIGHT  FROM SOURCE1 GROUP BY FOODTYPE);
```

Comment: When broken down, this is actually more complex than the answer I suggest in the question. You've added the column `lv` into the source table, when in fact it's not part of the source-data at all.  To get the `lv` value in the first place, you first need to group the source-data.  So in fact, you end up with 4 `SELECT` statements, instead of my 3 (or 3 instead of 2, depending how you count).  Clever use of the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` though.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse, I have updated my answer and provided an alternative solution with total select 2.

Comment: But that gives the wrong oputput.  The fruit total gives me the answer of `51`, when I'm expecting `31`.  You still have to group the source.